# Scrolling to bottom of div without using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an internal live chat system using Firebase. I make this call to get a list of all chat messages:

```
firebase.database().ref('chatrooms/'+this.roomkey+'/chats').on('value', resp => {

    this.chats = [];
    this.chats = snapshotToArray(resp);

    setTimeout(() => {
        if(this.content._scroll) { this.content.scrollToBottom(0); }
    }, 1000);

});
```

In my view I have this HTML to loop through the chats:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let chat of chats" no-lines>
      <div class="chat-status" text-center *ngIf="chat.type==='join'||chat.type==='exit';else message">
        <span class="chat-date">{{chat.sendDate | date:'short'}}</span>
        <span class="chat-content-center">{{chat.message}}</span>
      </div>
      <ng-template #message>
        <div class="chat-message" text-right *ngIf="chat.user === nickname">
          <div class="right-bubble">
            <span class="msg-name">Me</span>
            <span class="msg-date">{{chat.sendDate | date:'short'}}</span>
            <p text-wrap>{{chat.message}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-message" text-left *ngIf="chat.user !== nickname">
          <div class="left-bubble">
            <span class="msg-name">{{chat.user}}</span>
            <span class="msg-date">{{chat.sendDate | date:'short'}}</span>
            <p text-wrap>{{chat.message}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And here is my relevant CSS:

```
ion-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  .item-md, .item-ios {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

There are currently 30 chat messages. They are loaded from Firebase and then after a second, when the setTimeout finishes, the user is automatically scrolled to the bottom of the page so they can see the most recent message. This makes the page load a bit odd with the jump down to the bottom of the page after a second.

Is there any way to replace the timeout with something that will achieve the goal of the user initially seeing the most recent messages? Maybe there is some trigger that can be made that detects that `chats` has changed in the view and then does the scroll? This would seem better than a fixed 1 second pause?

Comment: Using the 'value' event you are listening to the entire set of data at that location. Maybe by using one of the other listeners (e.g. `child_added` or `child_changed`) you could find a smoother solution that would be more user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scroll to the bottom of the list when changes to the list of chats are detected:

- Associate a template reference variable to the `ion-item` elements (e.g. `#chatItems`)
- Use `ViewChildren` to get the `QueryList` of `ion-item` elements
- In `ngAfterViewInit`, subscribe to the `QueryList.changes` event
- Scroll to the bottom of the list when the list changes

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item #chatItems *ngFor="let chat of chats" no-lines>
      ...
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```
export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChildren("chatItems") chatItems: QueryList<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scrollContentToBottom();
    this.chatItems.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.scrollContentToBottom();
    });
  }

  scrollContentToBottom() {
    if(this.content._scroll) { 
      this.content.scrollToBottom(0); 
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Note: I used `QueryList<any>` because I don't know the `ion-item` component type. You can put the appropriate type if you know what it is.

Comment: Hi, this is a great help, thank you. If I now click the button to open my chat modal window then I am immediately scrolled to the bottom of the chat - perfect. If I then close the modal window, return to my app, use a different phone and send a new message, re-open the modal window on the first device ... I am not scrolled down. I remain at the top of the chat. I know that ngAfterViewInit is being triggered on the second open. Does the subscribe only detect the first change and not subsequent changes?

Comment: When you open the modal the second time, does the new message appear in the list? If it does, maybe the list is already complete in `ngAfterViewInit`, so that the `changes` event is not triggered. I modified the answer to add a default scroll, to account for that possibility.

Comment: I've updated the code based on your edits. Yes, the new message appears in the chat if I scroll down but still no change, on the second (and subsequent) opens of the modal window I am not scrolled to the bottom, I remain at the top! (thanks for help so far!)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot debug it here. Can you check with some `console.log` statements that `ngAfterViewInit` is executed each time you open the modal, and that the `changes` callback is triggered? I am not familiar with ionic, so I don't know if `this.content._scroll` is always `true` (or if that check is necessary).

Comment: It's bizarre. I've added a whole load of console.logs and the exact same events are being triggered each time. For the time being I have added a setTimeout of 100ms to the scrollContentToBottom function, this now makes each open of the chat modal window scroll appropriately.       
 setTimeout(() => { this.content.scrollToBottom(0); }, 100);

Comment: You could try to call `scrollContentToBottom` (without the timeout) in some [ionic life cycle events](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/), like `ionViewDidLoad` or `ionViewDidEnter`.